# Spel error in if statement(xml config)

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, spring-el

I am trying to use a `spel if statement` in xml configuration but with no success:

the part of xml:

```
<bean id="ExportReader"
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
                scope="step">
                <property name="resources" value="#{jobParameters['isIncremental'] eq 1? '${step3.index.incremental.folder}/#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}/*.xml' : true }">
                <property name="delegate" ref="staxPatentReader"></property>
                <property name="strict" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
```

The `${step3.index.incremental.folder}` work => resolves to `C:/` but the second part fails so I have resources like `C:/#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}/*.xml`

I imagine there is a problem escaping the single quotes...

Another thing is that this piece of xml works fine:

```
<bean id="indexFolderPartitioner"class="com.mycompany.FolderPartitioner" scope="step">
                <property name="folder" value="#{jobParameters['isIncremental'] eq 1? '${step3.index.incremental.folder}' : '${step3.index.full.folder}' }"></property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a SpEL it has an evaluation context with some variables. And it is a valid Java (almost) expression.

This should work:

```
<property name="resources" value="#{jobParameters['isIncremental'] eq 1? '${step3.index.incremental.folder}/' + stepExecutionContext['fileName'] + '/*.xml' : true }">
```

In this case the `jobParameters` and `stepExecutionContext` are EvalCtx variables, hence you should use them as is.

The `#{` is a start of SpEL, `}` - the end. Tipically you can't use sub-SpELs, as you show in your sample.

Since you are going to a string value from your SpEL, and some part are resolved from PropertyPlaceholder you should use string concatenation between those parts and that one, which should be resolved at runtime against Step evaluation context.

Note, property-placeholders are resolved on startup phase, hence they are just literals for the target SpEL at runtime.